# Why is the maximum port range 65535 in the TCP/IP Suite?

Tags: networking, tcp, ip, network-protocols, ports

My doubt is that - a port is just logical, so why such restriction ? Why can't I have a port of 9924593 or something like that ?

Comment: As much as we like to believe our abstractions have no limits, they do alas needed to be grounded in reality; especially if you look at networking and how many times network encapsulation is broken at various layers to make things efficient :)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Look at the [packet format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_segment_structure) for the TCP segment. The port identifiers are unsigned 16-bit integers, meaning that the largest number you can put in there is 2<sup>16</sup>-1 = 65535.