# Increase TCP port range on google cloud console

Tags: tcp, google-cloud-platform, port

I am trying to allow port beyond the 65535 range for a firewall rule, but I get a warning indicating it must be between 0-65535. I am using google load balancer.

Edit: Is there a way google console to allow a call in to port 80803 then would forward it to a valid one

Comment: Howdy .... Hmmmm ... I think you are misunderstanding something here.  A TCP/IP port number (by definition) is a 16 bit unsigned integer ... it can only ever have a value between 0 and 65535 (16 bits).  What is your thinking behind a desire to increase port ranges?

Comment: yeah i did not know this. We have a device calling into a server with the port 80803. is there any other solution like port forwarding?

Comment: Howdy ... still not clear here ... in the TCP/IP protocol, you simply can't have a port number > 65535.  Can you elaborate on what you mean by a device calling into a server on port 80803?  If someone has coded that as a port number to be used .... its simply wrong and, if accepted, then it may be truncated to 16 bits and should be error checked to ensure it is within range.

Comment: There was an error when port was being set to 80803. When we look at the device settings it does not truncate

Comment: Your device has a bug in its interface. Port 80803 does not exist. The maximum TCP or UDP port number is 65535 (2^16 - 1).

Comment: I think the device is not validating the port needs to be valid.

Comment: @GeorgeXia: *"When we look at the device settings it does not truncate"* - even if is not truncated in the settings in can only give 16 bit to the kernel so it gets automatically truncated. The device is likely using port 15267 (80803-65536).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich for my edification why does it translate to 15267. Why does it minus mine with largest possible.

Comment: @GeorgeXia: If you try to fit a 32 bit or 64 bit number into 16 bit it usually means that the last 16 bit are use, which essentially is doing [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) 2^16. Modulo 2^16 kind of means to subtract 2^16 again and again until the result is in the range of 0..2^16-1

Answer (score 0):

As @Kolban mentions, there is no way to have the port 80803 due to the fact that this is out of range. In case you are still having concerns about this, I think the response on the following post could provide you with more details.

[Why is the maximum port range 65535 in the TCP/IP Suite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36796183/why-is-the-maximum-port-range-65535-in-the-tcp-ip-suite)